# SQL - How to import a user as a new user with some tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, parameters, impdp

Hello beloved community,

Im trying to import an oracle database with the impdp command, and I want to import the already exported user A as User B with some specific tables. But I don't find any command line parameter for this operation.

Answer (score 1):

- user A to user B: `remap_schema`
- some specific tables: `tables`

For example:

```
impdp unb/pwb@db tables=usera.emp,usera.dept directory=expdir logfile=impdpab.log remap_schema=A:B
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it.